# Note check: Cassado cello solo suite 2nd movement, m. 74

Tags: sheet-music, accidentals, cello

The note in question is circled here: it's an F-natural in the 2 scores I found on IMSLP.  My teacher seems to remember that it should be F-#  as in the subsequent descending sequence.  Can anyone confirm either way?

[image: mm. 71–74, with m. 72 second note circled]

This passage occurs at the end of the *poco menu*, immediately before the return of *tempo I*.

Comment: What clef is this?! That's a B in bass, an A in alto, and a G in treble (and the 0 on the preceding note suggests bass). Seems a bit odd for it to become an F of any kind...

Comment: @AndyBonner it’s an F in tenor clef.

Comment: A.k.a. "cello clef" :)

Comment: @paulgarrett trombones and bassoons also use tenor clef fairly frequently (as did tenors until the 19th century, so you still see that occasionally, usually in reproductions of older prints and manuscripts).

Comment: @AndyBonner ***I suppose you did not notice the profile image of the user who asked the question.***

Comment: @AndyBonner That is not an "0" but the "thumb" indicator.

Comment: FWIW the consensus in a Facebook  Cello group is that it's F natural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overwhelming consensus from members of the Internet Cello Society (via FB) is that the first note is definitely F-natural.  they checked both the original published version and various early performances

Comment: Do they offer any explanation?

Comment: @Aaron  they checked both the original published version and various early performances

Comment: That's valuable. It should be part of your answer.

Comment: I listened to several versions on YouTube. About a third of them play F and two thirds F-sharp. Both versions are musically convincing.